# Script for incrementally creating records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Paul provided a useful script for the issue below but I would like to actually effect the changes. I can only see it if I use the select statement 
Please help with this one

Table name: Citizen

```
Firstname       Lastname    Telephone         Many other columns......
John             Smith      03907625212    
Andrew           Evans      0807452132    
Bill             Towny      05907122139  
Dame             Beaut      07894650569
```

I have over 150,000 records where the Telephone number needs to be adopted to a set format (set telephone area code and in incremental order) ie 01907000001, 01907000002 as shown below. There are other columns asides the firstname and lastname which will all remain unchanged..only telephone field requires this transformation.

It should ideally look like this:

```
Firstname       Lastname      Telephone         Many other columns......
John             Smith       01907000001   
Andrew           Evans       01907000002  
Bill             Towny       01907000003 
Dame             Beaut       01907000004
```

I will really appreciate some help or guidance on this.

Comment: What do you want the new incremental phone values to be ordered by? Eg. Should John Smith be 01?

Comment: yes please...auto increment starting with the first record

Comment: Check out my answer below.

Comment: Hi Paul, I would like to actually effect the changes. I can only see it if I use the select statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    [FirstName],
    [LastName],
    '01907' + --area code
    RIGHT('00000' + --middle padding for zero's
        CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [LastName]) AS VARCHAR) --incremental value
        ,6) AS 'Telephone' --6 characters plus area code

        --<< YOUR OTHER FIELDS
FROM 
    [AdventureWorks].[Person].[Person]
```

I used Adventure Works just to test it.

Change the ORDER BY clause in the windowing function if you want it to increment by something else.

Comment: Hi Paul, I can seem to get it to work following your advice                                                                                                        Citizen
select [All LP First Name]
      ,[All LP Other Second Name]
      ,[All LP Surname]
      ,[All Liable Partys PIN]
      ,'01907' + 000001
   RIGHT('00000' + 1
    CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [LastName]) AS VARCHAR),6) as 01907000001
   [Telephone1]
      ,[Telephone2]
      ,[Mobilephone]
      ,[EmailAddress]

Comment: Because you've stuck a load of stuff in that I didn't do! Try this: 
select [All LP First Name], [All LP Other Second Name] , [All LP Surname], [All Liable Partys PIN], '01907' + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [All LP Surname]) AS VARCHAR), 6) AS 'Telephone', [Telephone1], [Telephone2], [Mobilephone], [EmailAddress] FROM

Comment: My code comments in the script above were just for information. Not to be replaced with values. :-)

Comment: Fine, like this: select [All LP First Name], [All LP Other Second Name] , [All LP Surname], [All Liable Partys PIN], '01907' + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [All LP Surname]) AS VARCHAR), 6) AS 'Telephone1', [Telephone2], [Mobilephone], [EmailAddress] FROM

Comment: Hi Paul, I would like to actually effect the changes. I can only see it if I use the select statement

Comment: Ok, so you want an UPDATE statement rather than just a SELECT. We are probably reaching the limits of what can be done in these comments. SO isn't for discussion of endless scenarios. You could check out this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx But i'd advise caution when changing any data. Also I'd suggest some basic TSQL training.

Comment: thanks Paul...I have created a new topic for UPDATE. Kindly check it out  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39351001/script-to-update-a-column