# Script to update a column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Table name: Citizen

```
Firstname       Lastname    Telephone1         Many other columns......
John             Smith      03907625212    
Andrew           Evans      0807452132    
Bill             Towny      05907122139  
Dame             Beaut      07894650569
```

It should ideally look like this:

```
Firstname       Lastname      Telephone1         Many other columns......
John             Smith       01907000001   
Andrew           Evans       01907000002  
Bill             Towny       01907000003 
Dame             Beaut       01907000004
```

Earlier, someone was able to kindly provide a script using the select statement.
[Script for incrementally creating records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39348200/scipt-for-inreamentally-creating-records)

```
select [First Name], 
       [Last Name], 
       [All LP Surname], 
       [All Liable Partys PIN], 
       '01907' + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Last Name]) AS VARCHAR), 6) AS 'Telephone1', 
       [Telephone2], 
       [Mobilephone], 
       [EmailAddress] 
FROM citizen
```

I would however like the changes to be implemented as I can only view them if I use the above select script.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Some non-ANSI SQL there.)

Comment: Do you care about the order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No `JOIN`s are required for this.  You can update directly from a `CTE` using the value of the new column added.  I'm assuming you're wanting to set the `Telephone1` column equal to the computed `Telephone1` column of your query.  Here's the code for this:

```
;With ToUpdate As
(
    Select *,
           '01907' + 
               Right('00000' + 
                   Cast(Row_Number() Over (Order By [Last Name]) As Varchar)
                , 6) 
           As NewTelephone1
    From   Citizen
)
Update  ToUpdate
Set     Telephone1 = NewTelephone1
```

This will update your `citizen` table's `Telephone1` columns to be the values of the computed `NewTelephone1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE c
SET c.[Telephone] = '0' + CAST(1907000000 + t.RowNumber AS VARCHAR)
FROM Citizen c
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT [First Name], 
           [Last Name], 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Last Name], [First Name]) AS RowNumber
    FROM Citizen
) t
    ON c.[First Name] = t.[First Name] AND
       c.[Last Name]  = t.[Last Name]
```

Comment: the column now has new telephone numbers but they are very random...as opposed to the increment per row

Comment: You need to tell us how you want to create order here.  The query I gave you should order by last followed by first name.  If you want some other order, you need to specify it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So I want it in this other 01907000001, 01907000002, 01907000003, 01907000004 per row. All the other columns will remain the same, only the telephone1 field needs to be affected in this manner (in an incremental order starting from row 1)

Comment: There is no "order" inside your database table.  If you want to _see_ this order, then do the `UPDATE` and when you select the data out, order by the phone number ascending.  If you want to _update_ in a certain order, then you also need to specify that when computing the row numbers.

Comment: @optimisteve SQL tables represent *unordered sets*.  Unless you specify what exactly you want to order the records by, the order is non-deterministic.

Comment: How about if I want the telephone to start increments from 0190715001, ...the script currently has it starting from 000001,000002. what part of the script needs to change...ie to start from 01907150001, 01907150002, 01907150003? I attempted to change the '00000' to '15000' however, I can still see numbers below 15000 like 0190700005.

Comment: Just replace `1907000000` with `1907071500`, and leave the rest the same.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a CTE for the windowing function. Like this:

```
WITH cte AS
    (
    SELECT
        [All Liable Partys PIN], 
        '01907' + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [LastName]) AS VARCHAR), 6) AS 'NewTelephone1'
    FROM
        [citizen]
    )

UPDATE
    c
SET
    c.[Telephone1] = cte.[NewTelephone1]
FROM
    [citizen] c
    JOIN cte
        ON c.[All Liable Partys PIN] = cte.[All Liable Partys PIN]
```

I'm making an assumption here that we can use the PIN field to join on.

Comment: Cheers. How about if I want the telephone to start increments from 0190715001, what part of the script needs to change...ie to start from 01907150001, 01907150002, 01907150003?  I attempted to change the '00000' to '15000' however, I can still see numbers below 15000 like 0190700005.